# How to solve Flutter bottom overflow error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have tried to create Listview.builder with help of API(for displaying API product). but i got error in bottom pixel. i tried many ways to solve this problem. but couldn't find anything,
how can i solve this problems by editing code... And what is the main reason for this error

[image]

code is here

```
 Container(
                    height: 650,
                    child: FutureBuilder(
                        future: _getProduct(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.data == null) {
                            return const Center(child: Text("Loading"));
                          } else {
                            return GridView.builder(
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2),
                              itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 130,
                                    height: 485,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 240,
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                              child: Image.network(
                                                  snapshot.data![index].image)),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                            child: Row(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment
                                                      .spaceBetween,
                                              children: [
                                                Expanded(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                  snapshot.data![index].name,
                                                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                                  maxLines: 2,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w700),
                                                )),
                                                Text(
                                                    snapshot.data![index].price)
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          }
                        }),
                  )
```

Comment: A screenshot of overflow would be helpful to understand the problem

Comment: @SankethB.K Screenshot added

Answer (score 0):

Issue with this

```
GridView.builder(
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2),
```

---

Needed to add Shrinkwrap &  Add the Ratio

```
      shrinkwrap: true,
      gridDelegate:
                              const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner in flutter,

I changed to your code and working ok,

need a single line to be added to your code...

```
 gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.5,//<- add this one (it will increase height of your card or container)
 crossAxisCount: 2),
```